# cant add Jenkins linux slaves due to port is not reachable

Tags: jenkins

I am learning Jenkins, I started by setting up my master but when I am trying to add slave I am getting the below error:

```
INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, Ping]
Aug 10, 2022 3:39:02 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver isPortVisible
WARNING: connect timed out
Aug 10, 2022 3:39:02 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: http://20.204.5.47:8080/ provided port:34019 is not reachable
java.io.IOException: http://20.204.5.47:8080/ provided port:34019 is not reachable
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.resolve(JnlpAgentEndpointResolver.java:311)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:745)
        at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:544)
```

Incoming port 34019 is open on master. I am very new to this, can someone help?

-Shashank